# Partition key is not working while inserting in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: python, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert documents in Azure CosmosDB collection using stored procedure. Earlier I was not using partition key and this code was working but I came to know that for delete/update, partition key is required so I am passing a partition key also but while running the script it is giving following error:

> Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted.

This is the code:

```
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
import azure.cosmos.documents as documents
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import time
config = {
        'ENDPOINT': 'PUT_YOUR_ENDPOINT',
        'PRIMARYKEY': 'PRIMARYKEY',
        'DATABASE': 'DB_NAME'
    }

# Initialize the Cosmos client
client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url_connection=config['ENDPOINT'], auth={
                                    'masterKey': config['PRIMARYKEY']})

try:
    db_id = config['DATABASE']
    db_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(db_id)
    db = list(client.QueryDatabases(db_query))[0]
    db_link = db['_self']
except Exception as e:
    db = client.CreateDatabase({'id': config['DATABASE']},options={"offerThroughput": 10000})
    db_link = db['_self']

def get_data_from_collection(filter, collection_id, only_country_level=False):
    coll_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(collection_id)
    coll = list(client.QueryContainers(db_link, coll_query))[0]
    #print(coll)
    coll_link = coll['_self']
    offer = list(client.QueryOffers('SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.resource = \'{0}\''.format(coll_link)))[0]
    offer['content']['offerThroughput'] = 10000
    offer = client.ReplaceOffer(offer['_self'], offer)
    print('Replaced Offer. Offer Throughput is now \'{0}\''.format(offer['content']['offerThroughput']))

    data = []
    query = 'select value f.data from collection f'
    docs = (client.QueryItems(coll_link,query,{'enableCrossPartitionQuery': True}))#(client.QueryItems(coll_link,query).fetch_next_block())
    for i in docs:
        #print("docs: ",(i))
        data.extend(np.array(i).flatten())

    offer = list(client.QueryOffers('SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.resource = \'{0}\''.format(coll_link)))[0]
    offer['content']['offerThroughput'] = 400
    offer = client.ReplaceOffer(offer['_self'], offer)
    print('Replaced Offer. Offer Throughput is now \'{0}\''.format(offer['content']['offerThroughput']))
    #print(len(np.array(data).flatten()))
    #print("flat data: ",(np.array(data).flatten()))
    return np.array(data).flatten()

def store_in_cosmosDB(collection_name, dataframe):
    # Create container options
    options = {
    'offerThroughput': 10000
    }

    container_definition = {'id': collection_name,
    'partitionKey':
                {
                    'paths': ['/Country'],
                    'kind': documents.PartitionKind.Hash
                }
    }

    try:
        # Create a container
        container = client.CreateContainer(db_link, container_definition, options)
        coll_link = container['_self']
    except Exception as e:
        coll_id = collection_name
        coll_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(coll_id)
        coll = list(client.QueryContainers(db_link, coll_query))[0]
        coll_link = coll['_self']
        offer = list(client.QueryOffers('SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.resource = \'{0}\''.format(coll_link)))[0]
        offer['content']['offerThroughput'] = 10000
        offer = client.ReplaceOffer(offer['_self'], offer)
        print('Replaced Offer. Offer Throughput is now \'{0}\''.format(offer['content']['offerThroughput']))

        query = """SELECT VALUE f._self FROM collection f"""
        #delete_bulk(query,client,coll_link)

    sproc = {
                'id': 'storedProcedure',
                'body': (
                    'function (data) {' +
                    'data = JSON.parse(data);' +
                    '   var client = getContext().getCollection();' +
                    # ' for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){' +
                    '   client.createDocument(client.getSelfLink(), data, {}, function(err, docCreated, options) { ' +
                    '   if(err){ throw new Error(\'Error while creating document: \' + err.message);}' +
                    '   else {' +
                             '   getContext().getResponse().setBody(1);' +
                    '        }' +
                    '   });}')
            }

    try:
        # Create a container
        created_sproc = client.CreateStoredProcedure(coll_link, sproc)
        proc_link = created_sproc['_self']
    except Exception as e:
        proc_id = sproc['id']
        proc_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(proc_id)
        proc = list(client.QueryStoredProcedures(coll_link, proc_query))[0]
        proc_link = proc['_self']


    #dataframe.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    dataframe.fillna("(blank)",inplace=True)
    dataframe.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], "(blank)",inplace=True)
    df_list = np.array_split(dataframe, 50)
    size = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    # for split_df in df_list:
    #     json_temp = dict()
    #     json_temp['data'] = split_df.to_dict('records')
    #     size += len(split_df)
    #     st = str(json_temp).replace('\'','"')
    #     #print(st)
    client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(proc_link, json.dumps(dataframe.to_dict('records'), default=str), {'partitionKey':'India'})

    print("split size is ",size)
    # for item in df.to_dict('records'):
    #     client.CreateItem(container['_self'],item)


    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    offer = list(client.QueryOffers('SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.resource = \'{0}\''.format(coll_link)))[0]
    offer['content']['offerThroughput'] = 400
    offer = client.ReplaceOffer(offer['_self'], offer)
    print('Replaced Offer. Offer Throughput is now \'{0}\''.format(offer['content']['offerThroughput']))

data = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India','India','India'], 'num_Patients':[12,36,100]})

try:
    store_in_cosmosDB("dummy_data",data,None)
    print('Uploading Done!!!')

except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the `PartitionKey` value in the document that you're trying to manipulate in stored procedure is an array having `['India','India','India']` whereas when you're executing the stored procedure, the value specified for the same is `India`.

The values should match.

Comment: So you mean that I have to send one row at a time in dict format. Right?

Comment: You can do that or loop through the dictionary so that for each document the `PartitionKey` value is `India`. I have a suspicion that you actually want to do that i.e. store the dictionary as 3 different documents.

Comment: It works with one row at a time using loop. Just one doubt what if I have more than 100k rows. Is this the correct way performance wise?

Comment: I honestly don't know an answer to that. Sorry.

Comment: Alright. I'll check that. By the way thanks a lot. I was trying to solve it from past few days. :)